Visualizing SQL Data using Generative AI
I am seeking a solution for data visualization using Generative AI that works on databases containing multiple tables. While I have found solutions like PandasAI and LIDA that work with a single CSV file or a single SQL table, I need something more comprehensive that works with multiple tables stored in a database.
I am developing a chatbot using Streamlit that can take user input in natural language, query a database with multiple tables, and generate visualizations on the front-end.
If you know of any tools or methods that can achieve this, please let me know.

Not very sure if I completely understand your question. For front-end UI, which can be integrated with LangChain, I would recommend langflow or flowise. Basically they both supports

LangChain workflow (similar to LangGraph)
Visualized relationship


I'm asking something similar to Q and A in Power BI where a user can mention a query and the visualization gets generated. Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks for the response.

No. I did not get a solution.
